# Efficiently manipulating tuple values?

Tags: c++, tuples

I've not used `std::tuple` much in C++ and I have the following tuple:

```
std::tuple<int, int> range {0, 100};
```

This is the range for my mysql query:

```
prestmt_ = con_ -> prepareStatement("SELECT example_value FROM example_table  WHERE example_column = '0' LIMIT ?, ?");
prestmt_ -> setInt(1, std::get<0>(range));
prestmt_ -> setInt(2, std::get<1>(range));
```

I'm using a tuple structure to make it clear that the two integers are coupled together in the operation of the function.

I need to increment both tuple integers after each query:

```
range = std::tuple<int, int>(std::get<0>(range) + 100, std::get<0>(range) + 100);
```

This re-assignment looks really poor and isn't very readable. Is there a better way of editing these tuple values?

Comment: How about a temporary variable?

Comment: I don't think the MySQL query has anything to do with the actual question, or does it?

Comment: It provides context as too why I'm using std::tuple, instead of two integers.

Comment: Variable names like `prestmt__ ` are reserved for the implementation; you should not be creating such names in your code.

Comment: @NeilButterworth trailing `__` is okay no? Isn't just `__prestmt` that would cause undefined behavior?

Comment: Trailing `single` underscore is OK - you are not allowed to use double underscores anywhere in your own names. And using underscores at all is generally a waste of time in a strongly scoped language like C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::get<N>(x)` returns an *lvalue reference* to the `N`th tuple element if `x` is an *lvalue*. You can therefore say:

```
std::get<0>(range) += 100;
std::get<1>(range) += 100;
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nOpCx0Mok6uiBaYy)

---

For readability, use a *function* or *lambda*:

```
const auto increaseRange = [](auto& x, auto increment)
{
    std::get<0>(x) += increment;
    std::get<1>(x) += increment;
};
```

Usage:

```
increaseRange(range, 100);
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4Tp7CqXqLwKjgXua)

---

Alternatively, consider creating your own `integer_range` class instead of using `std::tuple`. It could support an `extend` method that does what you want and have *named fields* which would be easier to read compared to `std::get<N>(...)`:

```
template <typename T>
struct integer_range
{
    T _begin, _end;

    constexpr integer_range(T begin, T end) noexcept
        : _begin{begin}, _end{end} 
    {
        assert(_end >= _begin); // additional safety
    }

    void extend(T increment) noexcept
    {
        _begin += increment;
        _end += increment;
    }
};
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NxkWnvCx5fHbWbCV)